# How to send and receive file on Silverlight application?

Tags: .net, silverlight, networking, sockets

I am writting Silverlight client-server application.
Server part is WinForm application an client part is Silverlight.
I use TCP connction. I use sockets for sending and receiving information. But now I need to send a file, size of which may be greater then 1 Mb, so I can't use socets to send that file as bite stream. I wont to send that file form server and receive it on client Silverlight application.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you can't send a file > 1MB with sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current silverlight file download/upload limit (using sockets) is 30 mb (I've been told), so I think something more than 1 mb shouldn't necessarily by a problem.

don't forget to modify your config files!

for more information on changing your config files and large file uploads see:
[Official Silverlight Forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/21513/76994.aspx)

As for uploading files: you can always consider ftp file upload...